# How to create a bean for CrudRepository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to add a Database Loader to my Spring App, however I'm getting the following error:

```java
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org...GameRepository] found
for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this 
dependency. Dependency annotations: {}"}}
```

I've read about instantiating the Repository, but I've also seen several examples where that's not needed, so what exactly am I missing? Do I need some configuration class where I enable `@EnableJpaRepositories`?

```java
//GameRepository.java
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends CrudRepository<Game, Long> {
}
```

```java
//DatabaseLoader.java
@Component
public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner{

    private final GameRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(GameRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        this.repository.save(new Game("Sala 1"));
    }
```

```java
//Application.java
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that can be componentscan skips the repository packages? it gets param basepackages, i think worth to try

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc`. Replace `@ComponentScan` with `@SpringBootApplication`. Restart your application. Also make sure that your `Application` is in a top-level package so that it scans all of your classes. Else it might leave out some classes and not do proper auto-detection of features you might need.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add @EnableJpaRepositories to your configuration

Comment: Or he could use `@SpringBootApplication` which by default enables technologies enlisted in classpath.

Comment: hi i am new to spring boot n facing the same prblm mentioned on post , i dont know where is configuration for this above question and i tried in all class files none worked